# Where is the official Apple documentation for the Terminal App? I need a list of escape sequences

Tags: terminal

`Terminal.app` does not implement all `xterm` sequences. I need to get the complete list of what it does implement. Is it available anywhere?

Comment: in Terminal window hit the TAB twice, it display with a list of all commands, about 1400 of them :(

Comment: @Buscar웃 those are the shell commands. Th OP is asking for the sequences to move the cursor which are emitted by commands etc

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit vague... what sequences are NOT implemented?  One simple solution would be to see if [iTerm2](http://www.iterm2.com/#/section/home) is a better fit to your needs.  Incidentally, have you tried:

```
~$ cat .bashrc
export TERM=xterm-256color
```

(I am setting my TERM to xterm-256color in my bashrc, so that I get a number of xterm-256color behaviour by default).

Having said that, a few google inspired links that you might find useful, or not, depending on the sequences you are looking for:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1375184?start=0&tstart=0

http://taoofmac.com/space/apps/Terminal

Comment: The sequence that is not implemented is the one that changes the background color without having to clear the screen. I want each prompt to change the color so I know from screen color which machine I'm ssh'ed into.  I just checked and iTerm2 does not handle it. Here is the reference: http://superuser.com/questions/592090/change-xterm-change-background-color-without-clearing-the-screen/593228?noredirect=1#comment729128_593228

Comment: This is a tough one.  Are you ssh-ing from mac to Linux, from Linux to Mac or from Mac to Mac?

Comment: it occurs to me that you might want to change the colour of the user@hostname rather than the background -- it would require setting it up in the bash or whatever shell setting you use, but it would need to be done just once.

Comment: Actually, no. I really want the background changed, not the prompt. I got it working with applescript and the first hop, but the subsequent hops don't change.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not really sure that this is what you want, but...

Terminal -> Preferences... -> Settings -> (select your default theme) -> Keyboard.

Here you can see – and edit – a list of shortcuts. See also the "advanced" tab of the same panel.